# How to Add two rows together

Tags: sql-server

```
Name  Code  days
-----------------
aaaa   A      2
bbbb   B     -2
cccc   Q     -1
dddd   C      1
eeee   D     -3
ffff   A      3
```

This is my table in sql sever. Now i want to get the total of all the codes, count of names and the sum of days. But i want to add A and Q together as A.
So the table sould look something like this.

```
 count(Name)  Code  sum(days)
------------------------------
    3         A      4
    1         B     -2
    1         C      1
    1         D     -3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` to translate 'Q' to 'A' in aggregation:

```
select count(name),
    case when code = 'Q' then 'A' else code end as code,
    sum(days)
from your_table
group by case when code = 'Q' then 'A' else code end
```

Or using `IIF`:

```
select count(name),
    iif(code = 'Q', 'A', code) as code,
    sum(days)
from your_table
group by iif(code = 'Q', 'A', code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` to get the value of that row: `Select days from table_name where code=A`
After that, You can delete that row, by using `Alter`